# Перенос команд в sublime text 3

Tags: linux, cmd, sublime-text

В файле `.sublime-build` пытаюсь перенести команды в несколько строк, но при запуске такого файла:

`"cmd": [
        "echo test;",
        "echo tost"
    ]`

выводит только `test`
Пытался еще так:

`"cmd": [
        "echo test;\
        echo tost"
    ]`

но так вообще не может запуститься, пишет `no build system`

Так как же всё таки перенести несколько команд?

Comment: Для этого пользовался [**SequentialBuilder**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SequentialBuilder), также см. [**сюда**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/multi-step-build-scripts/6203/2?u=sasha_chernykh) и [**сюда**](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/multiple-cmd-in-build-system/3611/5?u=sasha_chernykh). Однако Build System — достаточно несовершенное средство, для любой задачи у меня находилось что-то получше. Реальный пример из Вашей практики вместо тестового можете привести? Спасибо.

Comment: @СашаЧерных да, конечно. Вот это пример того, что я хочу получить, но **это не работает**, т.к. я не знаю, как перенести. Файл компилит c++ код, если он изменился, копирует этот же код и добавляет туда цитаточку из `fortune`. https://paste.ee/p/HQUB8

Comment: Через [**Cpp Builder**](https://github.com/Sharlock93/CppBuilder) пробовали компилировать? Спасибо.